# Why are large amounts of magic numbers acceptable in CSS and SVGs?

Tags: coding-style, code-quality, css, clean-code, svg

Often times I see questions on the Hot Network Questions list like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470489/how-to-build-a-special-polygon-a-kite-shape-with-html-css-only) that basically ask "how do I draw this arbitrary shape in CSS". Invariably the answer is a couple of blocks of CSS or SVG data with a bunch of seemingly random hard-coded values that form the requested shape.

When I look at this, I think 'Yuck! What an ugly block of code. I hope I never see this type of stuff in my project'. However, I see these types of Q&As quite frequently and with a high number of upvotes, so clearly the community doesn't think they are bad.

But why is this acceptable? Coming from my back-end experience this makes no sense to me. So why is it OK for CSS/SVG?

Comment: What is a drawing, if not a random bunch of magic numbers (think of strokes between 2 (x,y) points, or arrays of pixels, etc.) that happen to look nice?

Comment: Does CSS have variables? Does SVG?

Comment: This is why many larger projects have a CSS preprocessor like SASS or LESS that supports variables.

Comment: @Oded There seems to be an experimental version of CSS that has something similar to variables: [CSS Custom Properties for Cascading Variables Module Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/)

Comment: @CodesInChaos - yeah I know. But currently... there are none.

Comment: @Oded For CSS, there is some 40% global support for variables (so, not recommended unless you want to tell all your Microsoft visitors that they're not welcome). Microsoft will probably follow the trend in Edge, and mobile devices will eventually catch up. SVG, on the other hand, has the concept of variables in some forlorn draft status document, but they'll probably never be implemented.

Comment: Why? Because they aren't magic numbers. CSS holds data, unlike a program which holds instructions. Although CSS is arguably turing complete, it is not a programming language.

Comment: CSS has variables and they work in Chrome today @Oded I have an extension that even utilizes them.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - still not a standard and not cross-browser. And certainly wasn't in CSS until very recently.

Comment: It's not just a "lack of variables" that's the problem with some of these answers (as already mentioned, there are no variables in stock CSS etc.), but the fact that many of these answers use a "magic number" without any explanation as to its meaning. In the accepted answer to the linked question, one of these values was questioned in comments and only then was an explanation given: "141% as 141 ~= √2 * 100 = the diagonal of the square". **(But isn't this a SO meta question, rather than a Programmers question?)**

Comment: @w3dk: I suppose if the question is "Why are questions asking how to draw arbitrary shapes with CSS so popular?" then yes, it would be more suited to MSO.

Comment: I hate to break it to you @David Grinberg, but I just opened some code files in a hex editor, and literally every line appeared to be ["seemingly random hard-coded values"](http://imgur.com/1lVv2OE).

Comment: Note that you really don't need SASS or other CSS-specific preprocessors. PHP can output CSS files just fine, and it is a language that you already know. Or ASP.net, or ..... Any language that can output HTML can output CSS as well.

Comment: @David Grinberg: I have the uneasy feeling that none of the answers actually respond to the kind of "magical numbers" you seem to refer to, unless I'm mistaken... You do mention SVG and shapes. Isn't it the path description language you happen to refer to? With longish sequences like `M800 700V600H600v200h100l-200 200-200`? Because if you do, that's something entirely different...

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Firstly, magic values are avoided in programming by using variables or constants. CSS does not support variables, so even if magic values were frowned on, you don't have much of a choice (except using a preprocessor as SASS, but you wouldn't do that for a single snippet).

Secondly, values might not be as magic in a domain specific language like CSS. In programming, a magic number is a number where the meaning or intent is not obvious. If a line says:

```
x += 23;
```

You will ask "why 23"? What is the reasoning? A variable could clarify the intent:

```
x += defaultHttpTimeoutSeconds;
```

This is because a lone number could mean absolutely anything in general purpose code. But consider CSS:

```
background-color: #ffffff;
font-size: 16px;
```

The height and color are not magic, because the meaning is perfectly clear from the context. And the reason for choosing the spefic value is simple because the designers thought it would look good. Introducing a variable would not help anything, since you would just name it something like "`defaultBackgroundColor`" and "`defaultFontSize`" anyway.

Comment: Some values are indeed just chosen because "they look good". But the example the OP linked contains the same value several times, but it's not clear if they represent the same thing or only have the same value by coincidence. Also it uses a value of `198px` which is the difference of the size of something else (`200px`) and a `2px` border.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Yes, there are some cases where variables or some kind of dependency expressions would be cool.

Comment: Note that CSS *does* [support variables](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/)

Comment: @phihag In the specs, yes, but [in the wild](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables), not so much (I don't consider 40% global support at the time of this comment as "widely supported". However, you're right in saying that, *in the future*, we will have CSS variables. And I did learn something new today, so thanks for that.

Comment: @phyrfox also, variables aren't needed in CSS.  Variables are made to vary/change (vary-able), and CSS is, at least as of now, a very static work environment.  There are some changes that can occur without JS, like the new transition/animations, but not much.  Though I can imagine that CSS will grow and become more complex and, in t future, may need variables.

Comment: And despite what their names suggest, cascading vars aren't even remotely related to the kind of variables that we use every day. The only reason the spec is called css-variables was to shut everyone up about "lack of variable support" in CSS compared to preprocessors, and based the way they work they *might as well be* vars - but look closer and you'll realize they aren't quite at all.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Polymer from google polyfills support for those declarations. Of course, I assume that means that they're shipping a CSS parser over the wire and doing it in javascript, but you *can* do it.

Comment: @JaredSmith Indeed you can do it. I can even implement an entire operating system in IE6 to run whatever program I want, but it is not practical.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I build polymer-based websites at work all day every day. I've not had any perf problems related to css custom properties. YMMV.

Comment: @JaredSmith It's fine for a relatively large scale webapp, however for common (perhaps static) pages including a huge polyfill is overkill.

Comment: The big laggard with css variable support is IE.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables  The real question is when will IE support it?  And when will enough people be using recent browsers for css variable support to be in the 90s percent wise?  Not for a year or two maybe, but it's coming.  Some of my pages are purely internal and no-one here uses IE (except when looking for things to break) so I can use css variables right now for those pages.  But I couldn't do the same for sites used by corporate customers locked into ancient versions of Windows.

Comment: The example in this answer does not make a convincing case. Something like `font-size: 16px` looks clearer because the value is specified with units, or in other words, because the type of the value (pixels) is very specific. There are programming languages in which you could write `x += 23s` (C++ user-defined literals come to mind). On the other hand, `x` is a bad example. In real code, the line would read like this: `httpTimeoutSeconds += 23`. And I really fail to see how the 23 in `httpTimeoutSeconds += 23` is more magic than the 16 in `font-size: 16px`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Magic numbers are a term for the use of literal numbers where the context does not clearly indicate why exactly this number is used. If the code makes you say "why 23? Why not some other number?" then it is a magic number. The units does not matter, the context does.

Comment: @JacquesB: Well, then, why 16 and not some other number?

Comment: @ChristianHackl: This is covered in my answer. But if anything is unclear I don't mind clarifying.

Comment: @JacquesB: You say it's 16 because the designers thought it would look good. But that's the same as saying it's 23 because the developers thought it would be a good timeout. This is all besides the point. `23` is a magic number if `23` is duplicated elsewhere in the code, with the same meaning, and there is no one single place in the code to change it. `16` is likewise a magic number if `16` is duplicated elsewhere in the code, with the same meaning, and there is no one single place in the code to change it. Fortunately, in CSS, relative values greatly diminish the need for constants.

Comment: @JacquesB: Example: You have three areas on the page which are designed to have the same text size, plus a another element which should be as big as the text in those areas. You end up with three different CSS declarations in which `font-size: 16px` is duplicated, and another one which says `height: 16px`. If you later want those areas to have smaller text, then you have to edit four different places instead of one. How is this not a magic number?

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Oh yeah you should not do things like that. If you have three areas which must have the same size, then you define the size either on a container element or on a class which you apply to all three elements. That does not just apply to the number, that applies to the whole set of declarations which are the same. Don't repeat yourself if you don't need to.

Answer (score 79):

It's acceptable because these formats are not *code*, but *data*.  If you were to remove all the "magic numbers," you would essentially duplicate every label, and end up with ridiculous looking files like:

```
mainkite_width = 200px
...
.mainkite {
  width: mainkite_width;
  ...
```

Every time you needed to change some data, you would need to look in two places.  Granted, there are situations where it's nice to avoid duplication, like if you have a color that is repeated frequently and you may want to change in order to change themes.  There are preprocessors and proposed extensions to address those situations, but in general, it's desirable to have numbers together with the structure in a data format.

Comment: +1 because :"It's acceptable because these formats are not code, but data."

Comment: "Granted, there are situations where it's nice to avoid duplication, like if you have a color that is repeated frequently and you may want to change in order to change themes." - Probably better done with classes anyway: `.main_color { color: .. }`, and using that class _is_ the method of deduplication

Comment: Code which determines the look and feel of an application is still code and not data.

Answer (score 25):

The prohibition on magic numbers is the primordial version of this design principle:

[Make decisions in one place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

But [these are not magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47888/1493294).  At least, not as far as any coding style guide I know of is concerned.

> width: 200px;
>     height: 200px;

They are clearly labeled.  Sure, the numbers happen to be the same.  But the width is the width and the height is the height.  They are designed to vary independently.

Now if you have 5 objects that all **had** to have the same width and each independently hardcoded their width I would beat you with the [indirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering) stick.

I wouldn't call them magic numbers if they are labeled, but I'd still beat you with the [indirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection) stick.

Comment: If you had enough objects to need a variable, you have enough objects to create a new class.

Comment: This is the best answer, as it shows the point: Those are not magic numbers.

Comment: " 5 objects that all had to have the same width and each independently hardcoded their width I would beat you with a stick." Welcome to the fun world of web design.

Comment: Magic numbers are not only problematic because of "Make decisions in one place" (aka DRY), but also because they are hard to understand.

Comment: Is there an alternative to being beat with a stick?

Comment: @dejeclin yes.  It's called indirection. It comes in many forms.  Code or data the answer is the same.  It being data is not a good excuse.  Most of the point of "normal form" in structured databases is trying to stop you from spreading one decision all over the place.  The only good reason for the same decision to be made in more than one place is if it really represents a different decision.  In that case, they don't HAVE to be the same.

Answer (score 10):

Because CSS is not a programming language, instead, it is the configuration file that contains the variable data for your program.

Currently CSS is so powerful that you *can* actually program in it, but that is besides the point. In essence it's still a [stylesheet language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_sheet_language).

Let's take a step back. Imagine we have a programming language that can draw on a screen. Imagine we want to program it to paint a web page.

At first we would enter tons of magic numbers in our code. The margin width, the text height, indentations, etc., etc.

```
jump(100) // The margin
drawTable(500, 500)
writeText("Hello World", 12)
```

So we extract the magic numbers, and put them on top of our file.

```
int margin = 100
int table = 500
int text_size = 12
jump(margin) // The margin
drawTable(table, table)
writeText("Hello World", text_size)
```

Now this is a bit ugly. We rather read our variable numbers from a configuration file.

```
margin 100
table 500
text size 12
```

Mm, that's a bit unclear... What do those numbers mean? What do those names mean? Let's formalize it a bit.

```
margin_left 10em
table_width 500px
table_height 500px
font_size 12px
```

But you know, we want to expand our program a little bit. We also want it to draw pages with multiple tables, pages without tables, pages with paragraphs or buttons and what more. Let's add selectors to our configuration file so we can specify what paragraph should have a larger font, or different text colour, perhaps we can support nested elements, perhaps we can use a general property in our configuration file, and then override it with a specific one in a few nested elements.

---

You feel where this is going, eventually you arrive as CSS. (And a browser to render it.)

Should we then add capabilities to our configuration file so we can avoid magic numbers again? Add variables? Add a configuration file for our CSS file? It feels a bit pointless if you remember our CSS file *is* that very same configuration file already.

But that is not true of course; your CSS file grows larger and larger, and eventually you run into the same problems as with the original magic numbers, the same number repeated all over the place, sometimes with a small transformations, etc.

Modern CSS however, allows many ways to avoid this repetition. You can use classes that apply to many elements, you can set style for all `div`s, but then override one specifically, and CSS 3 even allows some kind of variable usage.

That does not mean you need to start using CSS variable in every possible location. Use it where it makes sense and use it where you avoid duplication or where other techniques also available fall short.

In the end, you do not want too many magic numbers in your configuration file either :-)

Comment: Why does it matter where the redundancy is? Isn't maintenance going to be a problem no matter where it is?

Comment: @PeterMortensen This is always a consideration between low development time, or high maintainability. High redundancy is easy to develop because you can quickly change things here and there, low redundancy is easy on maintenance because you can quickly change global style. In practice you want to be somewhere in between the two, because face it, having a global style makes it a lot easier even to add new pages, but having every last obscure feature adhere any possible global style change takes forever to develop.

Comment: It's good CSS has features in both directions. And it is up to the web developer to decide how much time to spend on reducing redundancy and increasing maintainability, or time to spend at crunching out new pages/features. Interesting enough, the same holds true for any other programming language where you can spend months to lay out the perfect design, or days to whack down your program, and months to hunt down impossible bugs.

Comment: Interesting enough i just ran into [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/315128/what-is-soft-coding-really) that talks about taking abstraction too far, and losing out on both maintainability and development time.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is it [a bunch of seemingly random hard-coded values] OK for CSS/SVG?

It isn't OK. It's *possible* to write and maintain plain ".css" files, but eventually random hard-coded values will become a prevalent burden.

For anything other than extremely simple webpages, you will either have to develop a disciplined "find and replace" strategy, or use a CSS preprocessor with variables, or define styles via JavaScript.